# CSS grid and nested elements

Tags: css, grid, nested

Imagine you are using a CSS grid system and your page components are divs, snapped to the grid with a border radius.

If you wish to nest such components, the distance between the parent and child component must be at least a column width - right?

What if you want a smaller distance?

What if you want to nest up to 3 or 4 levels?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need the children to also be aligned to the grid? Generally grid systems are most useful for top-level page structure. Also, do you have any padding on your outer div (which contains nested divs?)

Answer (score 0):

> If you wish to nest such components, the distance between the parent
>   and child component must be at least a column width - right?

*Why are using border radius to line up blocks/columns in a grid? Shouldn't you be using margins?*

If you want to line things up in a grid, all grid columns must have a gutter.
What you're looking for in a CSS grid framework looks very much like [1KB Grid](http://1kbgrid.com).

If you want more flexibility, you can use the [Variable Grid System](http://spry-soft.com/grids/). From what you're proposing, there really isn't a need for you to use a custom grid or make a css grid framework.

Comment: No, sorry, I mentioned border-radius just because these components may or may not have a border (typically of 1px) and therefore this will influence the grid spacing.

Comment: Borders give elements a colour outside their dimensions, and divs with borders tend to push other divs out the way, provided there's not enough space for them to flaunt their border. What you can do, is give everything a border, and for items you don't want to have a (visible) border, you can make the border transparent.